# Spring data neo4j Index search

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using neo4j index to do full-text search for blogs, Since **findAllByQuery()** repository method doesn't work for pagination. I try to use (skip / limit) in cypher to achieve that.

```
@Query("START blog=node:blogSearch({0}) RETURN blog ORDER BY blog.createDate DESC SKIP {1} LIMIT {2}")
Iterable<BlogGraph> findBlogsByQuery(String luceneExpression, int start, int offset);
```

parameter: **luceneExpression** : "title: foo"

But I encounter some issues.

1, Got below exception, when first time calling method **findBlogsByQuery**. Apparently, index "**blogSearch**" has not yet been created, but how to create? If i use **findAllByQuery()** repository method, index will create when first i call it, from doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#d0e2031

```
Error executing statement START blog=node:blogSearch({0}) RETURN blog ORDER BY   
blog.createDate DESC SKIP {1} LIMIT {2}; nested exception is 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing 
statement START blog=node:blogSearch({0}) RETURN blog ORDER BY blog.createDate 
DESC SKIP {1} LIMIT {2}; nested exception is org.neo4j.cypher.MissingIndexException: 
Index `blogSearch` does not exist
```

2, Let's say index "**blogSearch**" has already been created, another issue(NullPointException) comes out, if search text include space, like below:

parameter: **luceneExpression** : "title: foo foo"

But i don't see this happen when use **findAllByQuery()** repository method

**BlogGraph.java**

```
@NodeEntity
public class BlogGraph {

    @GraphId Long id;

    @Indexed
    long blogId;

    @Indexed(indexName="blogSearch", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT)
    String title;

    ...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any updates on the status of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the attribute 'title' in your query:

```
@Query("START blog=node:blogSearch(title={0}) RETURN blog ORDER BY blog.createDate DESC SKIP {1} LIMIT {2}")
Iterable<BlogGraph> findBlogsByQuery(String luceneExpression, int start, int offset);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your query won't work, let's why i pass the whole luceneExpression as a parameter, see my **luceneExpression** : "title: foo".